Is sha2(256,columns())) a safe calculation in ADF?
I'm trying to calculate a hash of some columns in Azure Data Factory. I've seen advice in other questions to use functions like sha2(256,columns())). This seems safe at first glance, but what I've found is that these two expressions generate the same hash:
sha2(256, "ABC", "DEF")
sha2(256, "AB", "CDEF")

So it seems like the hash functions, when passed multiple parameters, just concatenate them all together before generating the hash. As the source data above isn't the same but generates the same hash, this doesn't seem to do what you'd expect.
Is there a best practice for generating a different hash from different data like the "ABC", "DEF" and "AB", "CDEF" above, especially when it comes to a dynamically-generated list of columns? Or am I missing something?

Add a custom concatenation; (delimiter) :"ABC", "-myconcat-", "DEF") AB-myconcat-CDEF /  ABC-myconcat-DEF will produce different hashes. This will still risk duplications if your custom delimiter string is found natively in the data being concatenated but it's a much smaller risk area.

Also SHA256 has a much small hash collision window which is what you're suffering from here.

I do agree with @Martin that adding a string in between the data might be a workaround for it.
If you want to do this dynamically for all the incoming columns, first you need add a constant unique string in between the concatenated columns data. To add it dynamically for all rows at different indexes, use the below expression.
concat(left(concatWS('',columns()),mod(length(concatWS('',columns())),10)),'HiRakesh',substring(concatWS('',columns()),add(mod(length(concatWS('',columns())),10),1)))

It will add the string HiRakesh at random indexes like below.

Now, use sha2(256,<column_name>) on this column in next transformation to get the result.


Thank you. I'm currently investigating how easy this is to do and if it gives a safe result if the incoming columns aren't of type string (because there may be a difference between how the sha2 function treats a non-string data type compared with me just converting it to a string manually before interleaving it with a constant string).
